# Android - always force close when using tabActivity

Tags: android

I have a question about android tabactivity.
I just use one .java and two .xml files to try to develop a simple tab view, but it failed :(

Here is my Main.java

```
public class Main extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
       tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("page1").setIndicator("Page1").setContent(R.id.view1));
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

This is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And this is abc.xml (included view1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/view1">
<TextView android:text="ABC"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

could you help me to review the codes? :(
thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have the `logcat` output?

Comment: Show your Log Cat output, please. It should give us the error and the place it happens at within your code. Also provide the code of the  `getTabHost()`.

Comment: Everything you posted looks fine, so I'm guessing the answer lies in view1.xml... could you post that?

Comment: I just realized `getTabHost()` is a method of the `TabActivity`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Just a guess - should the `LinearLayout` in the abc.xml also include `android:orientation="vertical"` attr?

Answer (score 1):

Your id/view1 LinearLayout has to be a child of id/tabcontent FrameLayout.